# How iOS mobile app scans and connects to RPi 2 with external Bluetooth module Using BLE

Tags: ios, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm new to RPi. Need to know if there's any way to get the ***RPi 2 with external bluetooth module using BLE*** can be spotted/listed using CoreBluetooth in iOS ?

I've tried scanning using iPhone but the external BLE module cannot be spotted.

I think i've found code which implement the same using noje.js . Please checkout the following :
https://www.hackster.io/inmyorbit/build-a-mobile-app-that-connects-to-your-rpi-3-using-ble-7a7c2c

Any kind of suggestions will be highly valuable !

Comment: If you RPi2 is advertising, then it can be found. But it has to be advertising. How did you scan with your iPhone? With Settings.app? Won't be found there in theory. With your own code? There could be an issue there. Did you try with LightBlue.app (available on the AppStore)?

Comment: Can you provide any code sniplet !

Comment: Snippet of what? In your question link, I spotted `leno.startAdvertising(bleno.name, [systemInformationService.uuid]);`, so it seems that it should work.